# composer conflict with laravel and kohkimakimoto/workerphp

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I am trying to use kohkimakimoto/workerphp to setup an internal cron for our cloud hosted app built on laravel. However, when I run composer install, it never updates the composer lock file nor does it install the workerphp repo. Here is the result of running the composer install:

http://laravel.io/bin/E3Lx5#19,32

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at line 55:
`- kohkimakimoto/workerphp v0.6.0 requires symfony/finder 2.6.*`

and one of line from 33 to 52:
`- laravel/framework v4.1.25 requires symfony/finder 2.4.* -> satisfiable by symfony/finder[v2.4.10, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.4.4, v2.4.5, v2.4.6, v2.4.7, v2.4.8, v2.4.9].`

It looks like using `laravel 4.1.*` you can't install `kohkimakimoto/workerphp v0.6.0`, because it requires `symfony/finder 2.6.*`, and your version of laravel accepts only `symfony/finder 2.4.*`.